# How to make RAD (v7.5) splash screen close

Tags: ibm-rad

I am having an unusual problem (who don't?), my launcher / splash screen opens but it keeps this state even after I choose the workspace and after RAD load the project. It only closes when I quit the entire software.
The last change that my RAD suffered before it starts to happen was the adding of some plugins to a project that uses Jasper and Crystal.

I already tried to use -clean parameter a thousand of times.